# Clarifying proof of Maximum Modulus Principle

Tags: complex-analysis, proof-explanation

In my complex analysis class today, my professor proved that a non-constant analytic function does not have any local maximum points on a domain. However, the first step of the proof was to say that it suffices to show that the real part of such a function does not have a local maximum point. The justification given for this was that, if $\lvert f(a)\rvert \geq \lvert f(z)\rvert$ for all $z$ in a neighborhood of $a$, then $\lvert e^{-i \operatorname{Arg}f(a)} f(a)\rvert \geq \lvert e^{-i \operatorname{Arg}a} f(z)\rvert$ for all $z$ in a neighborhood of $a$ and $e^{-i \operatorname{Arg}f(a)} f(a) \in \mathbb R$. I'm struggling to understand this justification though, because there is an  (a priori) difference between a function having a local maximum point where the function value is real and the real part of the function having a local maximum point. Could someone explain this further?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It is $e^{-i \mathrm{Arg}(f(a))} f(z)$.

Writing $f(z)=x(z)+iy(z)$ for real functions $x$ and $y$ with $y(a)=0$, one has $|f(a)|^2=x(a)^2$ and $|f(z)|^2=x(z)^2+y(z)^2$. So $|f|$ has a local maximum in $a$ $\Rightarrow$ $|f(a)|^2 \geqslant |f(z)|^2$ near $a$ $\Rightarrow$ $x(a)^2 \geqslant x(z)^2+y(z)^2$ near $a$ $\Rightarrow$ $|x|$ has a local maximum in $a$

The contrapositive is "$|x|$ has no local maximum $\Rightarrow$ $|f|$ has no local maximum"